# How to wait for a specific http status code - C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, http, http-status-codes

I have implemented this code, since 2 weeks now. Since then I am trying to improve my code because sometimes the Task.Delay method is not enough to wait the 3rd party API to send the correct http status code that I needed it. (They process is much longer than what I expected.)

```cs
var url = string.Format(_azureFormRecognizerConfig.RequestUrl, _azureFormRecognizerConfig.ResourceUrl, modelId);
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { source = storagePath }), Encoding.UTF8, _azureFormRecognizerConfig.MediaType);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    // Request headers
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(_azureFormRecognizerConfig.SubscriptionType, _azureFormRecognizerConfig.SubcriptionKey);

    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content))
    {
        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseLocationUri = response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            _logger.Information($"Error in httpclient { ex.Message } ");
        }
    }

    Task.Delay(20000).Wait();

    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(responseLocationUri))
    {
        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            _logger.Information($"Error in httpclient { ex.Message } ");
        }
    }

    _logger.Information($"Response headers { responseBody }");
}
```

As you can see in my code, I put a delay of 20,000 milliseconds (20seconds) just to handle the logic and expect that within that time the process is done and I can get the correct response and value.

Is there anyway, how can I improve this or make it work like a callback or something that I still didn't discover.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any value in the call to delay. You are awaiting the GetAsync so either it will return when its ready or timeout independent of the delay.

Comment: your `try-catch` block does not include the `await GetASync` call, youu may want to change it.

Comment: @Ralf as you can see before calling the GetAsync, I put above the Task.Delay method so that, when that code is being run there will be like a delay jumping next to another line.

Comment: Increase the timeout maybe? The returned response should have the `StatusCode` property you can check

Comment: @frz3993 - the timeout works, but is there anyway to handle it differently? because sometimes they are like process that can be done in 5 seconds, and I have added the 20 secs delay already, it seems like not ideal in the long run.

Comment: @FritsJ Still don't see it. You wait for 20 seconds and then you start the call. What influence should have that to the call happening 20 seconds later?

Comment: I have edited my post. Hope it helps for better understanding of my post.

Comment: Now i see. With the code before the delay it may start to make sense.

Comment: @Ralf before the delay, I sent a request to process the document, that I wanted, it will take time for sure thats why I put delay between them and in the second method after the delay, I can get the details of the document that I have requested to process it.

Comment: `Task.Delay(20000).Wait();` Using `Wait()` on a `Task` is asking for trouble. Since you're already in an async function, use `await Task.Delay(20000);` instead.

Comment: I don't think you need the delay because you `await` ed the response to the first call. I think what you want to do is if the first request is successful proceed with the second request, right?

Comment: The problem here is that your 20 seconds is entirely arbitrary. You don't know exactly (from this code) how long that api will need before your second call. It has nothing to do with "response codes". Does that api have another call you can make which reports when it has processed whatever you need it to process? If not, the best you can do is keep trying until you get the response you're after.

Comment: @frz3993 no, the first method is always correct. I just send the document to 3rd party to API to process it, they have different API to get the details of the document that I have processed that's why theres a delay between of them.

Comment: Have you considered to use polling? Issue a `HEAD` request if it fails then wait for a couple of seconds in async. Repeat it until the `HEAD` succeeds and the issue a `GET`

Comment: @Jamiec correct! and I want to improve my code to handle that logic.

Comment: Not being rude, but have you tried the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) because it's unlikely you're the first  person to hit this problem.

Comment: Does the API provide something like webhook and can you use that? If not, you can make a few retry for the get request with some delay between retries.

Comment: Can you point to the exact url you're using as it'll be easier to lookup a good solution for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume the API works as this:

1. You make a Post, this starts some computation on the server.
2. You make a Get with a url returned from the Post. This will succeed if the computation is finished, and fail otherwise.

To manage this you should use polling i.e.

```
while(true){
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(responseLocationUri)){
         if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
               // Handle success case
               return someResult;
          }
          await Task.Delay(1000); // Wait 1s between each attempt
     }
 }
```

You should probably also add a timeout or check the type of error code returned to avoid polling forever if the server never responds.

If you can change the API it might also make sense to use some kind of [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178210(v=vs.100)) instead of using polling, since callbacks usually result in less resources being used.

Comment: I understand now, this is what I needed. Already have an idea on how to improve my code. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why don't you use HEAD? This implementation can stuck in the loop infinitely. It would be wise to maximize the retry count.

Comment: @Peter Csala The example is simplified to show the main point. But I do mention that some way to avoid a infinite loop would be needed.